# Como enviar datos de pycharm hasta arduino para movimiento de actuadores?

Tags: python, arduino, pycharm, serialport, pyserial

Tengo un problema, estoy trabajando con vision por computadora escrita en python, necesito que la información interactue con Arduino. Pero tengo un problema al envio no esta recibiendo creo que talvez es por el tiempo que toma los datos y por ello solo se queda en registrando nuevos datos y no llegan hasta Arduino.

```
com = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600, write_timeout= 10)
#open de webcam
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#getting the frame wisth and height
frame_width=int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
#4-character code of codec used to compress the frames this is jpg
#output.avi save a video of what we saw
out=cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P', 'G'),10,(frame_width,frame_height))
#upload the weight
#../the name of the folder i can call the folder outside of my code
model=YOLO('path/to/best.pt')
classNames = ["Green","Red", "Damaged"]

while True:
    #lee la videocaptura
    success, img = cap.read()
    #detections using yolov8 frame by frame
    results = model(img, stream=True)
    #once we have the results this creates bounding boxes
    for r in results:
        boxes = r.boxes
        for box in boxes:
            x1,y1,x2,y2=box.xyxy[0]
            #take the tensor of the corners into integers
            x1,y1,x2,y2=int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
            print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            #convert the coordinates into a rectangle
            #cv2.rectangle(imagen, start point, end point, color, thickness)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,0,255),3)
            conf=math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100
            cls=int(box.cls[0])
            class_name=classNames[cls]
            label=f'{class_name}{conf}'
            t_size = cv2.getTextSize(label, 0, fontScale=1, thickness=2)[0]
            c2 = x1 + t_size[0], y1 - t_size[1] -3
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1,y1), c2, [255, 0, 255], -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(img, label, (x1,y1-2),0, 1,[255,255,255], thickness=1,lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
            y3= y2 - y1
            x3 = x2 -x1
            if x3 > 363 :
                com.write(b'9')
                print("GRANDE")
            else:
                com.write(b'1')
                print("pqueño")
    out.write(img)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('1'):
        break
out.release()
```

En el codigo superior se realizo el cuadrado alrededor del objeto y se muestra el tipo de clase, luego con las coordenadas proporcionadas del rectangulo se realizo una regla de tres para colocar el tamaño respecto a lo que se necesita. Se envia un 1 o 9 dependiendo de si es grande o pequeño.
A continuación el código de arduino

````
#include <Servo.h>
//Declaramos el servo
Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
//Declaramos las variables
char dato;

void setup() {
  // Configuracion de Comunicacion
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  // Declaracion de servos
  servo1.attach(9);
  servo2.attach(10);
}

void loop() {
  servo1.write(0);
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    dato = Serial.read();
    delay(10);
    Serial.print(dato);
    if(dato == 1)
    {
      servo1.write(180);
    }
    if(dato == 9)
    {
      servo1.write(100);
    }
  }

} ```
````